# Is there a way of dynamically locating a change of path of a sub-folder/sub-file of my current c# Winforms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, directory, configuration, app-config

Is it possible to dynamically locate a certain folder/file?

For example, let's say I have got a configuration file that my application obviously needs to be able to read. Currently, the path to my configuration file is hardcoded.
However, let's say when I deploy the application, the client decides to move that configuration file in some other random directory. Can I make it so my application will be able to locate that random directory without manually changing it in the source code?

Another example, I also have a Logs folder which stores my log files to which I need to be writing constantly. Same as the configuration file, if the client decides to change the Logs folder somewhere else, I need to be able to dynamically locate it from within my code.

Thanks for any future suggestions.

Comment: You certainly could, but its a lot of trouble and might introduce more problems than it solves. The only way you could really do it is to search throw the entire directory tree looking for the existence of that file and pick it up if you find a match. But this is asking for trouble, what if another file of the same name, or at least similar enough to be considered a match, appears in the tree? No user should ever expect that their program will continue to work when they start mucking with the directory structure and the placement of critical files.

Comment: What does *[the] configuration file is hardcoded* mean? Have you set paths specific to your dev machine? Have you used `Application.StatupPath` or similar? If a config file that is vital is missing, you throw and exit. If the logging folder/logs are missing, you throw and rebuild, if possible. Or add a configuration panel that allows a user to specify/redefine these locations, if needed.

Comment: Any Software expects its configuration in a specific form in a (or more, but finite) specific location(s). Allowing the user to put it "anywhere" is (sorry) ridiculous. You already invested more effort into this than it's worth. Location of Logfiles is a different story. If you are using for example NLog or log4net, you can easily change the location (and really a whole lot of logging config) via the respective configuration (which itself is expected in specific places, though).

Comment: If you really really cannot do without, I only see one possibility, but it needs user coop: You start out with the configpath setting set to null. If your app starts and finds it null, it will popup a dialog requesting the path to the config and save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to approach this problem is to use relative paths in your code. Your application needs to somehow get paths to folders / files it calls for. In case that relocating folder with Logs is a priority for you and you are willing to have a file with path (which cannot be relocated):

```
/filePaths.something
```

Then you can store (be it in plaintext, json, xml, binary or whatever) paths to the other files / folders. Eg:

```
{
  "logsFolder": "C:/Some/Random/Folders",
  "anotherFile": "D:/Client/Can/Edit/This"
}
```

You can also try scanning entire filesystem but there are several drawbacks:

- time consuming process
- probably will return multiple hits when scanning for a folder named Logs (non unique name)

There are probably milion of milions files on your client PC, scanning recursively just for folders will speed this up a bit but still it's gonna be very lenghty.

Another approach might be conneting your app to a database but that really doesn't differ from the first option described above. All in all you'll probably need to go some mid way to satisfy both technical limitations and your clients.